# Join two dataframes and overwrite matching rows [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

I've looked around and found a lot of similar questions, but nothing that answers my question, so here it goes.

I want to join two dataframes in R by column (like in rbind) and have the second table overwrite matching values of the first column such that there are no repeats of values for the first column

I want to do something like this:

```
a<-data.frame(c("Foo", "Moo", "Boo"), c(1, 2, 3), stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(a)<-c("Name", "Value")
b<-data.frame(c("Boo", "Bar", "Bat"), c(11, 12, 13), stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(b)<-c("Name", "Value")

rbind_and_overwrite(a, b)

# Output
#             Name         Value
# 1           Foo          1
# 2           Moo          2
# 3           Boo          11
# 4           Bar          12
# 5           Bat          13
```

I'm sure I could do it with a bunch of messy for loops, but I was wondering if there was some fast and elegant way to do it because my tables are somewhat large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use `%in%` to test for `Name`s in b that aren't present in a, and then only `rbind()` those rows onto `a`.

```
rbind(a, b[!b$Name %in% a$Name,])
#    Name Value
# 1   Foo     1
# 2   Moo     2
# 3   Boo     3
# 21  Bar    12
# 31  Bat    13
```

Comment: It seems so simple now! To have the b names overwrite the a names instead of the other way around I'll just have to do rbind(a[!a$Name %in% b$Name,], b). Thanks!

Comment: this is actually not the correct answer given the OP, it does not overwrite matches, but leaves the original rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the game, but the accepted answer is in  fact not correct given the OP: it does not overwrite the matching row, but leaves the original (row 3: Boo, 3 in the example).

I can't come up with an elegant solution, best I can do is this dplyr pipe, but it gets the job done correctly:

```
library(dplyr)
> a %>% 
+   filter(!Name %in% b$Name) %>% 
+   bind_rows(b)
  Name Value
1  Foo     1
2  Moo     2
3  Boo    11
4  Bar    12
5  Bat    13
```